# Get last statement result in embedded IronPython v2

Tags: c#, ironpython

[This post in Mike Stall's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031235957/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jmstall/archive/2005/09/01/howto-embed-ironpython.aspx) states that

> The last expression result is stored as the global variable `"_"`, so you can retrieve it like so:
>
> ```
> object o = m_python.GetVariable("_");
> ```

But currently in v2 scope has no such variable after executing, e.g.,

```
scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("a=1+2;a+1", SourceCodeKind.Statements);
```

Is there any way to access result `(a+1)` without explicitly define variable?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect with IronPython 2 you need to use SourceCodeKind.Interactive.

I'll try it out later and see if this works.

Comment: With SourceCodeKind.Interactive result is null as well as "_" variable unavailable.