# IronPython: Changing behaviour of SourceCodeKind.InteractiveCode

Tags: c#, ironpython

I can execute IronPython in C# with:

```
ScriptSource Source = PyEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(Code, SourceCodeKind.InteractiveCode);
CompiledCode Compiled = Source.Compile();
Compiled.Execute(PyScope);
```

This means that I can execute `A=1` and then `A`. This will then output `1`.

Is there a way I can override this behaviour so `A` will be redirected to a C# function, say `CustomPrinter` before printing? I know I can 'overload' the `print` function as described by https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871861/1447657 but I feel there should be a better way.

**Edit 1**

Thanks for your answers but I was slightly unclear about my aims.

I know I can redirect output with `PyEngine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(stream, encoding)` but I wish to retrieve the output value before it has been cast to a string. So if `A=[1,2,3]` `IronPython.Runtime.List` instead of a `string` is recieved.

I'm not sure if this is even possible without changing the IronPython source code or using a Regex to wrap variables on their own (like `A`) in the `CustomPrinter.Write` function

Comment: After Edit 1: Is there any reason to avoid using `SourceCodeKind.Expression`?

Comment: @PawelJasinski Thanks, I hadn't realised what that did. I Googled it and came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966421/get-last-statement-result-in-embedded-ironpython-v2 which is effectivly what I wanted to do. I'm now just doing `object Result = Compiled.Execute<object>(PyScope);` which works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can `PyEngine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(stream, encoding)` to direct what would go to `stdout` to a custom stream (see also `.SetErrorOutput` for `stderr` and `.SetInput` for `stdin`).

Answer (score 0):

you can implement file object (in this case you need only write method accepting string) and assign it to sys.stdout.

```
public class PythonFile {
    public void write(string s) {
    }
}
```

and later:

```
PyEngine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("stdout", new PythonFile());
```