# Capture python print statements in C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am writing a C# component which takes an ironpython function as a parameter.

```
    def test():
        x=x+1
        print "Test"
```

C#:

```
    var v = engine.Operations.Invoke(scope.GetVariable("test"));
```

Var `v` returns `null` for `print` statements. It works only if I have `return(x)`. Can I capture print statements using ironpython?

Comments and links are appreciated. Also, can just capture it using commandline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I redirect the stdout of ironpython in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055002/how-can-i-redirect-the-stdout-of-ironpython-in-c)

Comment: The above link works if I have "sys.stdout". My script only has print command?

Comment: The print statement uses `sys.stdout` by default. (See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3263763/539465)

Comment: try
        {
            var strExpression = @"
def test():
        x=x+1
        print "Test"

            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            var sourceCode = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(strExpression);
            scope.SetVariable("test", this);
            var actual = sourceCode.Execute(scope);
            textBox1.Text += actual;
        } I tried this but does not work for me

Comment: how about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21754433/1761490

Comment: Thanks Pawel, the above solution works: but how can I capture return can you help me with "return"?  My code below: public class PythonFile
    {
        public string write(string s)
        { return (s)}} How can I capture this with engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("stdout", new pythonfile() )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```cs
using IronPython.Hosting; 
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting; //provides scripting abilities comparable to batch files
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text;

var script = @"import sys
def test(): 
    print sys.version
    print >> sys.stderr, 'this goes to stderr'
    return 42";

var scriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scriptScope = scriptEngine.CreateScope();
scriptEngine.Execute(script, scriptScope);
var testFn = scriptScope.GetVariable("test");
var streamOut = new MemoryStream();
var streamErr = new MemoryStream();
scriptEngine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(streamOut, Encoding.Default);
scriptEngine.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(streamErr, Encoding.Default);
scriptEngine.Operations.Invoke(testFn);
Console.WriteLine("returned: {0}", scriptEngine.Operations.Invoke(testFn));
Console.WriteLine("captured out:\n{0}", Encoding.Default.GetString(streamOut.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine("captured err:\n{0}", Encoding.Default.GetString(streamErr.ToArray()));
```

Output:

```
returned: 42
captured out:
2.7.5b2 (IronPython 2.7.5b2 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 2.0.50727.5477 (64-bit))

captured err:
this goes to stderr
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pawel. I really appreciate your help but can you please answer my above question also above solution explaination if possible. you can give me links too.Eagerly waiting for the response!

Comment: I am confused. Can you restate the question which you would like to have answered?

Comment: Can you please answer both? I don't know: if Method #1 is used then how can we have return value since it is in different class. And using stream we are able to capture Output?

Comment: Can you update your answer to say how to capture `stderr` or say why it's not possible?

Comment: Gabe: Use `scriptEngine.Runtime.IO.SetError` instead.

Comment: @Gabe, I have added capturing of stderr

Comment: @PawelJasinski: Why doesn't scriptEngine.Operations.Invoke(testFn); work for serial communication? It goes in infinite loop? Can you send me some links where I can get detailed info about above topic?

Comment: @user2801184, can you show us exactly what you are doing? A runnable snippet would be ideal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620217/iron-python-error-expected-type-bytes-or-bytearray-got-type-str-for-se/24628437#24628437

Comment: Please check the above link!

Comment: let me know if you need more explaination? Appreciate your help Buddy!

Comment: Hi Pawel, I was wondering if we can pause a python script using C#? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have a new question, please start a new separate entry. If it is clearly ironpython speciality you can try our mailing list https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/ironpython-users or chat https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/ironpython