# Iron Python Error: expected <type 'bytes'> or bytearray, got <type 'str'> for Serial comm

Tags: python-2.7, ironpython

Unable to understand this: When I run using python shell it works but doesn't:  when invoked using Iron python. It throws above error

C#:

```
scriptEngine.ExecuteFile(path);
var testFn = scriptScope.GetVariable("InputSelection");
var stream = new MemoryStream();
scriptEngine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(stream, Encoding.Default);
scriptEngine.Operations.Invoke(testFn);
```

Python:

```
def send_data(message,check):
    if message:
        ser.write(message.encode('utf-8'))

    time.sleep(2)
    response = ser.read(1024)

def InputSelection():
    send_data("Hello","Hello")
```

Comment: Can somebody recommend me some other way of to handle  sendReceive data in serial?

Comment: Can somebody recommend me some other way of to handle  sendReceive data in serial? I am using python 2.7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting [a bug](https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/34842) in IronPython. In the meantime you can workaround it by using:

```
ser.write(bytes(message.encode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: I have already tried above soltion: I get no response for this  statement goes scriptEngine.Operations.Invoke(testFn). Not able to understand why?

Comment: can you communicate with a device without using IronPython?

Comment: @user2801184 can you communicate with a device without using IronPython?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly if I run it from Python Shell! Can I use Iron Python different version? Will it solve the issue?

Comment: Was unable to connect to unit as scriptEngine.Operations.Invoke(testFn). never threw an error saying com port was open!!