# IronPython Requests Error: expected <type 'bytes'>

Tags: python, python-requests, ironpython

I'm new in python, I'm trying to post to https API with  JSON I use IronPython 2.7 and requests, python 2.7 
here is my code

```
import requests
import json

def PostData(uri, Timestamp, ProxyIP, ProxyPort, username, password, UserAgent, Joson):

   payload = {"Timestamp": Timestamp}   
   headers = {"user-agent": UserAgent,
              "ContentType" :"application/json"}

   r = requests.post(uri,params=payload,json=json.dumps(Joson))

   return r.text
```

but I always get error :

```
IronPython Requests Error: expected <type 'bytes'>
```

even if I just use
`requests.post(uri)`
how to fix this problem? Thanks for help

Comment: How do you call `PostData`? Why are you using ironpython?

Comment: As @RafalS said, why are you using IronPython?

Comment: ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
var searchPaths = new List<string>();
string path = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName;
searchPaths.Add(path);
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
engine.ExecuteFile(@"D:\PythonCode.py", scope);
dynamic PostData = scope.GetVariable("PostData");
var ResponseResult = PostData(
"https://dev.com/session.php",
 "1576171885","185.233.201.218", "9841","soycXq","rSFASE", "",StaticUrls.JsonSession);

Comment: i use IronPython beacuse i devlop c sharp desktop to send  web request but the dot web request is slow so i want to use python requests inside my c sharp app  to make it fast

Comment: i read there is issue in ironpython on handling encoding but i do not know how to fix fit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620217/iron-python-error-expected-type-bytes-or-bytearray-got-type-str-for-se

Comment: this issue  coming only when i use requests

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `bytes` as uri:

```
requests.post(bytes(str(uri).encode("utf-8")))
```